# Proving that a set is bounded.

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that $\{(x, y): x^2+ xy + y^2 = 1\}$ is a bounded set.

That is for any $(x,y)$ belonging to that set, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le a$ for some $a\gt 0$.

Comment: Sometimes a bit of calculus can help with locating a maximum (if it exists), or with showing there is no maximum.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
|xy|\le\frac{x^2+y^2}2\implies xy\ge-\frac{x^2+y^2}2
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+y^2}2
&=x^2+y^2-\frac{x^2+y^2}2\\
&\le x^2+y^2+xy\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* The condition can be rewritten as
$$\left(x+\frac12y\right)^2+\frac34y^2=1. $$
Or - if you prefer - as
$$ \frac34(x+y)^2+\frac14(x-y)^2=1$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2+xy+y^2=1$, then $|x|+|y|$ is at most $1$, since $(|x|+|y|)^2\geq x^2+xy+y^2$.
It follows that the curve $x^2+xy+y^2=1$ (that you may easily check to be an ellipse) lies inside a square centered at the origin with side length $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$x = r cos(\theta)$;  $y = r sin(\theta)$;

$r^2 cos^2 (\theta) + r^2cos(\theta)sin(\theta)$ + $r^2sin^2(\theta) = 1$;

$r^2  + r^2 cos(\theta)sin(\theta) =1$;

$r^2 (1 + (1/2) sin(2\theta)) = 1$;

$r^2 = \frac{1}{(1 + (1/2) sin((2\theta)}$;

$-1  \le sin(2\theta) \le 1$;

$r^2 \le 2$, I.e. $x^2 + y^2 \le 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The equation is:
$$
y^2+xy+x^2-1=0
$$

solve for $y$:
$$
y=\frac{-x\pm\sqrt{4-3x^2}}{2}
$$

since $y$ must be a real number, this means that $x$ is must be in  the interval $[\frac{-2}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}]$

Do the same solving the equation for $x$ and find the limits for $y$.